Why do flaps affect Vmc?
While looking at several Type Certificate Data Sheets for business jets, I have noticed that there is a common theme relating to their VMC in that the VMC (airborne) are lower when the flaps are deployed than when the flaps are retracted.
I have heard this effect accounted for in light piston twins through the process of only one engine producing thrust and propeller wash over one of the flaps, thus creating a differential drag on either of the flaps. With only one engine accelerating air over the wing and associated flap, the two flap panels would effectively see different airspeeds and resultant drag values such that there was a stabilizing yaw force created.
This explanation doesn't seem to apply to the business jets as they have engines mounted to the rear of the fuselage and therefore have no flap to “blow over” as in the case of the piston twins.
It appears there is little to no information available in several textbooks and online sources I have perused trying to figure out how this works. The “what” is answered easily, it's the “why” that remains elusive.
This leads to the question: how does flap extension affect directional stability and the associated VMC (airborne)?

Well, I dont know :) but I offer two educated guesses: At least for A320 the increasing flap setting decreases VMCG so could it be that the "net thrust" of the remaining engine is lower with higher drag, thus requiring less authority from rudder to maintain dierctional control. My other guess is that the flap setting affects the airflow around empennage and thus alters rudder effectivity.

Can you give some examples of business jets that have lower Vmc with flaps down even though their engines are aft of the flaps? The first few I checked list only one Vmc regardless of flaps setting.

Don't know about business jets, so not an answer but a comment. In the C-130, the hydraulic pressure to the rudder is reduced when flaps are up so as to avoid over-controlling the rudder. There may be a similar pressure-reducer at work in the jets you're seeing, where in order to give the rudder more authority at low airspeed, the pressure is greater with flaps extended than with flaps up. Also, I'd expect VMC's with tail-mounted engines to be much lower than with wing-mounted engines (which have more moment-arm, i.e. leverage), vis-a-vis the rudder. Can you link to the data you're looking at?

Good point @RalphJ.  Also worth noting, the EA-6B had extended rudder throws with flaps down due, (if I remember right...) to a mechanical rudder stop retracting.  It's likely that these sort of features answer the question, but the details are probably aircraft specific.

The bottom line up front is static Vmc is a function of more than just directional stability. It’s a full 6-DoF trim that’s impacted by many variables. Side, normal, and axial forces have to balance (net zero) as do rolling, pitching, and yawing moments. For a given speed and weight, etc., adding flaps results in more lift and hence less angle-of-attack (AoA) is required to trim. On most configurations, rudder and roll control effectiveness are decreased at higher AoA’s. Therefore, with the flaps extended there is more roll and yaw power available to trim at a larger sideslip angle.
Vmca is very airplane and configuration-dependent, especially since it can be set by multiple factors. For example, pedal force or rudder power limits may be reached before the 5 deg of bank limit. So, it’s not just about directional stability or even aerodynamics generally but also the propulsion system, mass properties, and flight control system. Furthermore, there are both static and dynamic requirements. So, yes, it is complicated.
FAA part 25, section 149(a) through (d) describe FAA Minimum Control Speed, Vmc (also known as Vmca) requirements and AC 25-7D, Flight Test Guide for Certification of Transport Category Airplanes provides valuable additional information.

This answer is, more or less, "It's really complicated and I don't understand ..."  The sentence that starts with "For a given speed and weight, etc., adding flaps results in more lift and hence less angle-of-attack (AoA)... " is the beginnings of the correct answer, but the ability to trim is not a factor.

No, it's complicated and I do understand. The static requirement is evaluated by the FAA in flight test where the goal is to fly a constant heading at constant speed and the prescribed contstant engine settings and evaluate what the steady state values are for bank angle, etc. "Trim" is common term in aerospace engineering used to refer to a static flight condition, usually (but not always) zero angular rates and accelerations. It does always refer to time-invariant inceptor inputs. Note this is not the same as 'trim' as in reducing control forces by use of tabs or other means.

No, it's really simple.  Higher drag requires more power. More power (with only one engine running), means more yaw (sideslip) At or near clean Vmc, you are in a high AoA, High drag regime. You require close to full rudder to maintain directional control. Putting the flaps down means lower AoA, less drag, less asymmetric thrust, and so you now have excess rudder available to maintain control. So your Vmc is lower.  I don't understand what trim has to do with this. If you are using an engineering term (other than the common GA understanding), you can't just throw it out without explaining it.

I have never heard an adequate explanation of this as well.  Charles Bretana hints at an idea here.  I might offer that flaps, in altering the overall camber of the wing, decrease the stalling “speed” of the wing i.e. reducing the AoA, thereby increasing control authority at lower speeds, allowing the pilot to maintain directional control than would otherwise be possible with a wing in a cruise configuration.  Another safety advantage here is that, in reducing stalling speed, it helps gives a larger margin between speeds when rudder authority is lost and when the critical AoA is exceeded, reducing the risk of a stall in an uncoordinated condition.

A simpler answer is that flaps lower the Angle of Attack necessary to produce the lift to maintain 1-G level flight at any specific airspeed. So they reduce the minimum airspeed necessary to maintain level flight. At low airspeeds (where AOA is above L/D max AOA), induced drag increases as you slow, so drag is lower at this lower AOA. This means power required to maintain that airspeed is also lower. This is why this is called "behind the power curve".
The lower the power output at the point an engine fails, the less asymmetric thrust there will be. So with the flaps down, you can slow to a lower airspeed than you can with flaps up, and still maintain direction control if/when an engine fails.

Vmc is always defined with the operating engine at a specific critical power level, isn't it? I'm also very skeptical of your assertion that it takes less power to maintain airspeed with flaps down. Flaps increase drag, which increases the power required to maintain a given airspeed.

Yes, flaps increase drag at a given airspeed and AOA, but if you are at high AOA, (like close to a stall) with flaps Up, putting them down increases the camber of the wing, and increases Lift  (and drag) but if you lower the AOA to get back to the same amount of Lift (whatever is required to maintain level 1-G flight), then the AOA and drag will be substantially lower.

.. and VMC is defined (as I recall) as the minimum airspeed at which directional control can be maintained on only the critical engine running at that power setting required to maintain level 1-G flight at that airspeed. At any lower airspeed, drag is Higher, so yaw/sideslip due to asymmetric thrust is higher, rudder effectiveness to counter the yaw is less, so the VMC for this higher drag AOA will be higher.

@Romeo understands... You can fly slower with the flaps down. Clearly, drag, in any configuration, in this regime increases as airspeed decreases closer to the stall (Clmax) AOA. So with both engines running or not, you can fly slower with the flaps down. If you are at or near Vmc and an engine fails, putting the flaps down immediately reduces the AOA (and power) required to maintain level flight. With less power, you have less asymmetric thrust, so you can slow down more, (not that you'd want to!), and still maintain directional control

That may be true when you're very close to a stall, but in general flaps increase drag more than they increase lift. Flaps steepen an airplane's glideslope exactly because they make level flight require more power.

But also Vmc is defined with "Maximum available takeoff power or thrust on the engines;" and Vmcl is defined with "Go-around power or thrust setting on the operating engine(s)" so that isn't relevant anyway unless the deployment of flaps on the type in question limits the available power.

@Chris, But that's exactly what we're talking about when we're discussing Vmc.  A High AoA, Low airspeed situation where rudder effectiveness is low, (because we're slow), and drag is high. (behind the power curve). We can fly slower with the flaps down! Why? because the high camber flaps down wing produces more lift and lower induced drag than flaps up wing. True, the Flaps down wing has higher form drag than the flaps up wing, but at slow airspeed (behind the power curve most of the drag is Induced drag, (drag due to Lift), and this is much higher with flaps up, since AoA is higher.
